# Missing argument list bracket error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
app.get("/editMBTI", editMBTIFunc(req, res)
{
    // making MongoClient available to all the EJS Files
    // app.locals.MongoClient= MongoClient;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected Successfully to the Database server");
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        //getting the whole collection of MBTI sets
        var cursor = db.collection("mbti_testcontent").find();
        cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
            console.log(doc);
            //send the above retrieved doc to the editMBTI.ejs file(front- end)
            res.render('editMBTI', {
                'mbti_content': doc,
                'db_url': url,
                'dbName': dbName
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The above is the code and the image of the terminal(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcOti.png). Why is the missing argument bracket error poping up in the editMBTI api ? I have closed all the brackets that were opened. Where is it missing ?

Comment: You have wrong brackets pairing. Look at your 'connect' expression: what parameters are you sending to it? where is the maching close-bracket for these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
app.get("/editMBTI", editMBTIFunc(req, res)
```

to this:

```
app.get("/editMBTI", function editMBTIFunc(req, res)
```

FYI, a tool like JSHint or JSLint will often give you more detailed info about where something is wrong (which is what I used to see this more easily).

Comment: Thanx man !! How could I miss that. Anyway thank-you so much :)

Comment: @user9273551 - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points on stack overflow for following the proper procedure here.